# Calculating coordinates in a grid based off centre position

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to calculate the coordinates for points in a grid with a given distance (in meters) between each.

I have the Long, Lat of a central point and need to get a list of coordinates for all the points forming a 3x3 or 7x7 or 9x9 grid around the central point?

I'm guessing I would add the distance in meters to the coord each way until I have the sufficient amount, but don't really know where to start.

Any assistance is appreciated!

[image: Grid of points around a center]

Comment: This should steer you in the right direction; https://stackoverflow.com/a/29700240/1739852

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution, hope it works.

```
    $grid_size=9; 
    $spacing=10; 
    $position_x=15; 
    $position_y=15;

    $half=floor($grid_size/2);
    for($i=-$half; $i<=$half;$i++){
        for($j=-$half; $j<=$half;$j++){   
            $points[$i][$j]['x']=$position_x+$i*$spacing;
            $points[$i][$j]['y']=$position_y+$j*$spacing;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Farzad. Would this work with long and lat coordinates?

Comment: @KriiV Yes. Sure